# Programatically creating an SVN patch / diff file in C#

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

Using SharpSVN I can easily revert an SVN checkout programmatically in C#, but now I need to create a patch / diff file just prior to performing the revert.

SharpSVN has the SvnClient.Patch API but docs / intellisense indicate that this is for applying a patch to a repo, whereas I need the equivalent to create the patch file in the first place.

How can I programatically create an SVN patch file in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

To Create a Patch file from SVN, you can also create a "Unified Diff" file across revisions. Following code is based on the same. It will create a unified Diff file of the changes done across specified revisions.

```
                System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("your url path");

                using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
                {
                    SvnUriTarget from = new SvnUriTarget(uri);

                    // To Get the Latest Revision on the Required SVN Folder
                    SvnInfoEventArgs info;
                    client.GetInfo(uri, out info);
                    SvnRevisionRange range = new SvnRevisionRange(info.Revision - 10, info.Revision);   // The given input revisions should be valid revisions on the selected Repo path

                    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    if (client.Diff(from, range, stream))
                    {
                        stream.Position = 0;    //reset the stream position to zero, as the stream position returned from Diff method is at the end.
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\diffFile.patch", new System.IO.StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd());
                    }

                    stream.Close();

                }
```